# application loader inapp purchase import disappeared

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, application-loader

Until last week, we could import text files with several in-app purchases in application loader on MacOS. Now, we can only submit application binaries.
I try to find another solution to import several in-app at one time but with no success.
How to import in-app at one time now?

Answer (score 3):

I stumbled upon the same issue, and the new way of doing this is through **XML Delivery** using a command-line app called **Transporter**.

Data should be prepared in a specific format specified here:

http://help.apple.com/itc/appsspec/#/itc5b4d94692

Transporter tool user guide:

https://help.apple.com/itc/transporteruserguide/#/itc0d5b535bf

Comment: This change from Apple is ridiculous... Why would Apple do this?!

Answer (score 0):

With version 3.7 of Application Loader, **Apple no longer supports in-app delivery**:

> Application Loader 3.7 no longer supports in-app purchase delivery. You can create in-app purchases, add metadata, and set pricing using iTunes Connect. XML Delivery is also available to create in-app purchases and add metadata and pricing, as well as uploading hosted content associated with your non-consumable in-app purchases.
>
> Source: http://help.apple.com/itc/apploader/#/apdS73193199

Besides manually adding each product individually through iTunesConnect, I don't know if there's a way now to bulk upload products. Has anyone had any luck another way?

Comment: See my answer above. You have to use Transporter from now on.